# How do I use numpy arctan2 within polars dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, multiple-columns, python-polars

I am trying to use numpy arctan2 in polars dataframe. The code works outside of polars

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np 
data = pl.from_dict(
{'v': [-4.293,-2.4659,-1.8378,-0.2821,-4.5649,-3.8128,-7.4274,3.3443,3.8604,-4.2200],
'u': [-11.2268,6.3478,7.1681,3.4986,2.7320,-1.0695,-10.1408,11.2327,6.6623,-8.1412]})
```

this works

```
v = data ['v'].to_list()
u = data ['u'].to_list()
wd = np.round(np.degrees(np.arctan2(v,u).tolist())+180,3)
print(wd)
```

I tried dozens of variations of these ideas

```
data.with_columns([ ( np.degrees( np.arctan2( pl.col('v'), pl.col('u'),None )  ) + 180  ).alias('wd_ck')  ]).head()
data['wd']=data.select([pl.col('v'),pl.col('u')]).apply(np.arctan2,return_dtype=pl.Float64)
```

I am trying to calculate wd from v,u using arctans2 inside of the polars dataframe

I'm using windows 11, python 3.9.15, numpy 1.22.3, polars 0.16.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `map`:

```py
data.with_columns(
    [
        pl.map(
            ["v", "u"],
            lambda s: np.degrees(np.arctan2(s[0], s[1], None)) + 180)
        .round(3)
        .alias("wd_ck")
    ]
)
```

```
shape: (10, 3)
┌─────────┬──────────┬─────────┐
│ v       ┆ u        ┆ wd_ck   │
│ ---     ┆ ---      ┆ ---     │
│ f64     ┆ f64      ┆ f64     │
╞═════════╪══════════╪═════════╡
│ -4.293  ┆ -11.2268 ┆ 20.926  │
│ -2.4659 ┆ 6.3478   ┆ 158.771 │
│ -1.8378 ┆ 7.1681   ┆ 165.62  │
│ -0.2821 ┆ 3.4986   ┆ 175.39  │
│ ...     ┆ ...      ┆ ...     │
│ -7.4274 ┆ -10.1408 ┆ 36.22   │
│ 3.3443  ┆ 11.2327  ┆ 196.58  │
│ 3.8604  ┆ 6.6623   ┆ 210.09  │
│ -4.22   ┆ -8.1412  ┆ 27.4    │
└─────────┴──────────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: So `pl.map` allows you skip the need for `pl.struct().map` + `.field()` unpacking inside the callback? Very neat. Do you happen to know why `.with_columns(np.arctan2(pl.col("v"), pl.col("u")).alias("arctan2"))` does not "work"? It doesn't appear to be doing the same as `np.arctan2(data["v"], data["u"])` which I thought it would.

Comment: @jqurious, Polars seemlessly handles numpy functions that take a single Series/Expression.  But I've not gotten numpy functions to work when more than one Series/Expression is passed, unless I use `map` or `apply`.  I believe `apply` makes separate calls to the numpy ufunc for each and every row, whereas `map` will pass the entire Series to the vectorized numpy ufunc in a single call which is far more efficient.

Comment: Ah okay. It looks like with `np.arctan2(pl.col("v"), pl.col("u"))` it's passing `pl.col("v")` as both arguments, perhaps it's a "bug".

Comment: I think you want to use reduce here instead of map since arctan2 and degrees are ufuncs

Comment: @bgk I put an answer with reduce context that takes advance of arctan2 being a ufunc

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 2: Performance Plot** (the lower the better)

[image: Performance Plot]

---

**EDIT 1**: answer expanded after `@bgk` feedback in the comments

> maybe by using .with_columns() or .apply()

To create a columd `wd` within a dataframe:

```py
In [23]: data.with_columns([
    ...:     pl.struct(['v', 'u']).apply(
    ...:         lambda x: np.round(np.degrees(np.arctan2(x['v'], x['u'])) + 180, 3)
    ...:     ).alias('wd'),
    ...: ])
    ...:
Out[23]:
shape: (10, 3)
┌─────────┬──────────┬─────────┐
│ v       ┆ u        ┆ wd      │
│ ---     ┆ ---      ┆ ---     │
│ f64     ┆ f64      ┆ f64     │
╞═════════╪══════════╪═════════╡
│ -4.293  ┆ -11.2268 ┆ 20.926  │
│ -2.4659 ┆ 6.3478   ┆ 158.771 │
│ -1.8378 ┆ 7.1681   ┆ 165.62  │
│ -0.2821 ┆ 3.4986   ┆ 175.39  │
│ ...     ┆ ...      ┆ ...     │
│ -7.4274 ┆ -10.1408 ┆ 36.22   │
│ 3.3443  ┆ 11.2327  ┆ 196.58  │
│ 3.8604  ┆ 6.6623   ┆ 210.09  │
│ -4.22   ┆ -8.1412  ┆ 27.4    │
└─────────┴──────────┴─────────┘
```

---

To get the same result **without converting to list**:

```py
wd = np.round(np.degrees(np.arctan2(data['v'], data['u'])) + 180, 3)
```

Where the `arctan` is calculated as `v / u`:

```py
                         np.arctan2(data['v'], data['u'])
```

Then the `np.degrees`:

```py
              np.degrees(np.arctan2(data['v'], data['u'])) + 180
```

And the `round`:

```py
     np.round(np.degrees(np.arctan2(data['v'], data['u'])) + 180, 3)
```

---

A quick test to check the result against your example:

```py
In [11]: all(
    ...:     np.round(np.degrees(np.arctan2(data['v'], data['u'])) + 180, 3)
    ...:     == np.round(np.degrees(np.arctan2(data['v'].to_list(), data['u'].to_list()).tolist()) + 180, 3)
    ...: )
    ...:
Out[11]: True
```

Comment: thank you for the quick reply Filippo, I appreciate it.  The part missing is how to do it all inside of the polars dataframe, without converting v,u to lists, maybe by using .with_columns() or .apply() or a combination somehow.

Comment: I updated my answer @bgk using both `.with_columns` and `.apply`

Comment: In the `select` context `map` should be favored over `apply`. This will be much faster.

Comment: Thanks Filippo! This explained what I was doing wrong with my with_columns() and apply() approach. I wish I could vote for two answers, but the greek answer using map seems the way to go. For the record, I included both alternatives in our internal notes on how to use polars.

Comment: @ritchie46 I'm under the impression that ufuncs should be run with reduce (assuming 2+ arguments) rather than map.  Is that right or should we expect same performance from reduce and map with ufuncs?

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the other answers, they aren't taking advantage of the fact that arctan2 and degrees are [ufuncs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/numpy.html) which you can execute directly as an expression.

The somewhat confusing bit is that arctan2 takes two arguments and it isn't obvious how to get polars to operate on a function that takes two arguments.  The answer to that question is to use `reduce`.

For example,

```
df.select(pl.reduce(np.arctan2, [pl.col('v'), pl.col('u')]))

shape: (10, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ v         │
│ ---       │
│ f64       │
╞═══════════╡
│ -2.77636  │
│ -0.370523 │
│ -0.25098  │
│ -0.080458 │
│ ...       │
│ -2.509433 │
│ 0.289372  │
│ 0.525164  │
│ -2.663372 │
└───────────┘
```

For degrees, since it just takes one argument, you can use it directly and still have both functions in the same context, as well as adding 180 and rounding...

```
df.select((np.degrees(pl.reduce(np.arctan2, [pl.col('v'), pl.col('u')]))+180).round(3))

shape: (10, 1)
┌─────────┐
│ v       │
│ ---     │
│ f64     │
╞═════════╡
│ 20.926  │
│ 158.771 │
│ 165.62  │
│ 175.39  │
│ ...     │
│ 36.22   │
│ 196.58  │
│ 210.09  │
│ 27.4    │
└─────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

This now works as of [polars v0.16.18](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/7924)

```
df.with_columns(wd = 
   (np.degrees(np.arctan2(pl.col("v"), pl.col("u"))) + 180)
      .round(3)
)
```

```
shape: (10, 3)
┌─────────┬──────────┬─────────┐
│ v       ┆ u        ┆ wd      │
│ ---     ┆ ---      ┆ ---     │
│ f64     ┆ f64      ┆ f64     │
╞═════════╪══════════╪═════════╡
│ -4.293  ┆ -11.2268 ┆ 20.926  │
│ -2.4659 ┆ 6.3478   ┆ 158.771 │
│ -1.8378 ┆ 7.1681   ┆ 165.62  │
│ -0.2821 ┆ 3.4986   ┆ 175.39  │
│ …       ┆ …        ┆ …       │
│ -7.4274 ┆ -10.1408 ┆ 36.22   │
│ 3.3443  ┆ 11.2327  ┆ 196.58  │
│ 3.8604  ┆ 6.6623   ┆ 210.09  │
│ -4.22   ┆ -8.1412  ┆ 27.4    │
└─────────┴──────────┴─────────┘
```